# JPA Weak Entity Mixing @EmbeddedId and @Id

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to map a value object to an entity in DDD terms using JPA. Here is my example:

Company entity has a list of CompanyDetail.

I created a shared CompanyPk and used it as an @EmbeddedId in both to indicate that the PK of CompanyDetail is also a FK to Company.

This works well, but I also have another constraint.

CompanyDetails must also be unique by "service" so essentially I want the PK of CompanyDetail to be (company_id, service).

My initial approach was to use another @Id

```
@Entity
@Data
public class CompanyDetail {
    @EmbeddedId
    CompanyPk id;

    @Id // <-- not working
    String service;
    String detail;
...
}
```

But apperantly this is not allowed by JPA.

How can we implement this "weak entity" use case using JPA ?

PS: I hope I understand the notion of weak entity properly:

> In a relational database, a weak entity is an entity that cannot be
> uniquely identified by its attributes alone; therefore, it must use a
> foreign key in conjunction with its attributes to create a primary
> key. The foreign key is typically a primary key of an entity it is
> related to.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity

Comment: A weak entity is just an entity with a composite PK. You have to have a FK from CompanyDetail -> Company which you haven't shown: CompanyPk isn't a reference or foreign key, and shouldn't be marked as  embeddedId since JPA only allows one embeddedId to be the ID. Check out JPA examples on derived ID as there are a number of different ways to map this, but I'd add a reference to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (of many):

```
public class CompanyDetailPk {
  CompanyPk company;
  String service;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(CompanyDetailPk.class)
public class CompanyDetail {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns( {
        @JoinColumn(name = "column_1", referencedColumnName = "column_1"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "column_2", referencedColumnName = "column_2")
    })
    Company company;
    @Id
    String service;
    String detail;
...
}
```

CompanyDetailPk is then only used to pass to find calls. You can also make it an embeddable ID in the class if you prefer, and use the mapsId instead of ID on the ManyToOne (and remove the String service from the base class as it is redundant)

Comment: It seems that "@Id" cannot be used on an field that references "@Entity". For me "@MapsId" worked

Comment: If your JPA version is 2.1 or later with MapsId support, it has support for marking a *ToOne relationship as (or part of) the ID. If you have a problem, feel free to post the error you get as what I posted in the answer should work. Note you answer is now using Company ID as a basic Long companyId mapping which isn't right if you have an embedded ID in the Company object - if you really only have a single Long as the company ID, I don't know why you'd use an embedded ID. And MapsId("company_id") is wrong as the spec requires it to point at the java property "companyId" not the column

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using @MapsId and @IdClass.
We also tested with @EmbededId and works as well.

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CompanyDetailPk implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    Long companyId;

    String service;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@IdClass(CompanyDetailPk.class)
class CompanyDetail {
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    @Id
    Long companyId;

    @Id
    String service;

    String detail;

    @MapsId("company_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;

    public CompanyDetail() {
    }

    public CompanyDetail(String service, String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
        this.service = service;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "corporate_company")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
class Company {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CompanyPk id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long groupId;

    public Company(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = new CompanyPk(id);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company")
    List<CompanyDetail> companyDetailsWithEntities = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

As we can see it properly creates "company_details" 2 PKs in the table where one of them is a FK to "company".

[image]